# Django логгирование для файла и консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, логирование

Есть рабочий `django` проект, который имеет следующую конфигурацию для логгирования (`settings.py`)

```py
LOGGING = {                                                                                                                 
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'server.log',
        },
        'console':{
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
        },
    },
}
```

Все отлично работает и логи пишутся.

Иногда есть необходимость заходить в командную строку `django` через `manage.py`, вот так

```
(env) a@prod:~/path_to_manage$ python3 manage.py shell
```

На данном этапе получаю ошибку

> raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
> ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'logfile'

Мне объективно понятно, что в этом случае, я не могу получить доступ к файлу `server.log`. То есть, если заглянуть в логи, то я это вижу

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/path_to_project/server.log'

Кто знает как настроить конфиг, чтобы не было этого поведения. То есть, для того чтобы зайти сейчас в консоль `django`, мне необходимо закомментить `LOGGING` в настройках и тогда все работает, ошибки не получаю, но и логи (что логично) не пишутся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В действительности, все было ясно из самого вопроса. Проверил кто владелец файла и группу и все встало на свои места. Поскольку разворачивал не я не сервере, мне остается только догадываться как такое получилось.

В общем:

1. Проверил права доступа

```sh
ls -l server.log
```

Вывод

```sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    55602 nov.  26 12:11 server.log
```

2. И переопределил пользователя

```sh
sudo chown site_user:site_user server.log
```

3. Раскоментил `LOGGING` в `settings.py` и запустил

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

4. И ожидаемый вывод

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```